# Is there a better solution? Using GitHub and Google Drive

Tags: git, github

So I plan on moving back and forth between houses. I have all my GitHub projects on my main desktop PC, and I plan to buy another desktop PC for the 2nd place. I want to have all my local cloned repos from GitHub be synced exactly between the two PCs so I can pick up where I left off when I go to my 2nd place on my 2nd PC without having to keep committing my files on the 1st PC before I leave so I thought of placing my GitHub repos in my google drive but I read that this isn't a great idea.

My other solution was just to copy all my GitHub repos on my computer onto a portable hard drive using a program like FreeFileSync and then mirror the files onto my 2nd PC, but is there a better solution for my dilemma?

Comment: Do you turn off the PC in the place you are currently not or do you typically keep it running?

Comment: most likely won't leave it running so remotely logging in isn't an option for me

Comment: Don't use a cloud syncing service like Google Drive because that will almost certainly cause repo corruption.  Every solution which doesn't involve copying a busy repository will be better and safer.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a distributed version control system; it can solve your problem. ;)

First, [always work in branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) never on main. This keeps your pushes from interfering with other's work. It's just a good idea in general.

When you're done on one computer, do a WIP (Work In Progress) Commit. `git commit -a -m wip`. And push.

When you get on the other computer, pull your feature branch. It will have the WIP commit. Continue working where you left off. When you're done, push.

Repeat.

---

This does leave you with WIP commits in your history. You might not care about that. If you do, you can avoid them by amending the WIP commit; instead of making a new commit, meld your work into the existing WIP commit.

`git commit --amend`, reword the log message if necessary, and push your changes. Because amending a commit makes a new commit, you'll have to force push. This is safe if you use [--force-with-lease](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/): `git push --force-with-lease`. I alias this to `git repush`.

The flip side is if you `git pull` on the other computer you'll get an error because of the rebase. You can get around this with `git pull --rebase` (`git pull` is `git fetch` + `git merge origin/whatever`, `git pull --rebase` is `git fetch` + `git rebase origin/whatever`). I recommend to rebase pulls by default: [`pull.rebase=merges` in your .gitconfig](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase).